# How can I set the default call answer screen to my app's activity in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, call

I want to write an application that when phone is ringing, Instead of show default android screen, my Special َactivity shown. 
I should use `broadcast receiver` or `android.Intent.action.ANSWER?`
or use `telephonyManager` class?

Please help.

Comment: before kitkat it is applicable, but now those are deprecated it will not work check once.

Comment: but i see similar apps that do this work.

Comment: just tell me those appps. I will see that